# removing message text from browser

Tags: php, mysql

I created a php script that looks at whether the admin is logged in using PHP session. If they aren't logged in, the script sends them back to the last page they were on with an error message.

```
$Message = urlencode("  Authentication Timeout: 1");
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}?Message=".$Message);
```

And on the main.php page I have this code to check for the $Message:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_REQUEST['Message'])){
echo "<font color='red'>".$_REQUEST['Message']."</font>";}
?>
```

However, if this event is triggered, the browser show `?Message=TEXT` even after being returned. And the text that shows up as well as in the URL doesn't go away until you refresh the page. Another thing I noticed is that if you just add 
?Message=SomeText to the end of the URL, then the message code is triggered for that page, which is expected because the php code is searching for ?Message.

What would be the best approach for removing the text from the URL, but still being able to display the error message?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ZPm.png)

Comment: Use `cookies` or some other storage

Comment: Just store the message in a session. Then, on the other page, check if that session is set. If it is, show the message and delete it from the session (then it won't show on a refresh). That's usually called a "flash session".

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions

on the protected page:

```
$_SESSION['response'] = 'authentification failed';   // set message in a session
header('Location: '.$home);                          // Redirect to homepage
die;                                                 // stop executing the script
```

on the default page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['response'])){                    // check if session set
 echo $_SESSION['response'];                         // output Content of session
 unset($_SESSION['response']);                       // delete session
}
```

Comment: I tried to unset the session variable, but when the page is redirected back  to the admin area, over and over again, the text continues to stay. Logically, I would think that when the page is refreshed, that text would go away and issue the same error message each time. I set the time to 2 seconds just to test so I throw the error, but the text does not go away. See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ZPm.png

Answer (score 0):

Read about flash messages.
It is generally an approach to store a session of the message and if that session exists while the page load, then you show it to the user and remove that session.
So even after a reload the message won't be there anymore.

Before redirect:

```
$_SESSION['flash'] = 'text';
```

After redirect:

```
echo $_SESSION['flash'];
unset($_SESSION['flash']);
```

Of course you should do some isset validation.